# Issue with removing dates, symbol, exchange and volume from dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I coded something to retrieve historical price data from an app called TradingView

This is what the code looks like:

```
from pandas import set_option
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval

tv = TvDatafeed()

set_option('display.max_rows', None)

str = (tv.get_hist('NAS100','PEPPERSTONE',interval=Interval.in_daily,n_bars=100))

print(str)
```

One line of the output is:

```
2023-09-27  PEPPERSTONE:NAS100  14564.5  14565.9  14552.1  14555.7    3478.0
```

I'd like for it to look like this:

```
14564.5  14565.9  14552.1  14555.7
```

Is there a way to remove that information? Or a way to simply print the Open, High, Low and Close?

I tried adding a few extra lines of code or creating a separate program to enter the printed text into but to no avail.

Comment: I'm guessing the `tv.get_hist()` function returns a dataframe. Can you [edit] your question and put there output from `str.head()` (Also, don't use `str` as variable name, it shadows the python built-in function)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that yourself since I do not think this is possible, at least for the scenario given.

Here is how to implement a clamp function (that's how I named it anyway) in python that gets a string as the data to clamp and two integers on how many elements to skip from the start and end of the data given

```py
def clamp(data_raw, start_skip, end_skip):
    data_raw = data_raw.split(" ")
    data = []
    
    for item in data_raw:
        if item != "":
            data.append(item)

    data = data[start_skip::]
    data = data[::-1]
    data = data[end_skip::]
    data = data[::-1]

    return data
```

And after testing it like this (with the data you provided) it seems to work quite well

```py
print(clamp("2023-09-27  PEPPERSTONE:NAS100  14564.5  14565.9  14552.1  14555.7    3478.0", 2, 1))
```

OUTPUT

```
['14564.5', '14565.9', '14552.1', '14555.7']
```